# Absolute element in a scrollable element

Tags: html, css

I have a modal, with a max height modal-body. The modal-body has `overflow: auto`, which cuts the datepicker. Try to turn off the overflow, the datepicker will appear with its full dimension, but in the same time body's content will cover the modal's footer.

I want to have the modal-body scrollable (just like in the example), but I want to see the full datepicker.

Here is a demonstration of the problem:

```css
#page {
  background: #c4c4c4;
  height: 100vh;
}
#modal {
  background: #d4d4d4;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
#modal-body {
  background: #4d4d4d;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
#modal-header,
#modal-footer {
  background: #5d5d5d;
}
#datepicker {
  background: #a5a5a5;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="modal">
      <div id="modal-header">
        HEADER
      </div>
      <div id="modal-body">
        <div id="datepicker">datepicker</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
        <div>BODY BODY</div>
      </div>
      <div id=modal-footer>
        FOOTER
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

The datepicker is a 3rd party library (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), and it calculates its own position (top, left, etc.) I have no control over it.

Here is a more complete demo of the problem (with the actual datetimepicker plugin): https://jsbin.com/sopevaxogu/7/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You should link to which date picker library you're using.

Comment: Do you have a functional example?

Comment: @Jacob https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2):

You can set the popup datepicker to `position: fixed;` and without any `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` values, if they're already set from 3rd parties, you can use `!important` to reset them to `auto`, then use `margin` to control the position as needed.

**[jsBin](https://jsbin.com/babepuqoji/1/edit?html,css,output)**

There is another way, if you can modify the HTML to add a `div` in `modal-body`.

```
<div id="modal-body">
  <div id="modal-scroll">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#modal-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 30vh;
}
#modal-scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**[jsBin](https://jsbin.com/rifidalero/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Answer (score 0):

To show the full datepicker and have `#modal-body` scrollable, remove `top: -30px;` from datepicker. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLGJKb

Comment: datepicker is a 3rd party library, and it calculates its own position (top, left, etc.) I have no control over it.

Comment: @user3568719 please give us a working demo with complete code to reproduce the problem.